# Attempting to get authentication from server using Json token in Swift

Tags: json, swift, token, nsurlsession

I'm adding a Login process in my Swift app and have added the following code to handle the Json token authentication

```
 class func getValidationFromServer(success: ((svrData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
    var usrName = ViewController.gVariables.gUser
    var pwd = ViewController.gVariables.gPwd
    var postData = NSMutableData(data: "username=\(usrName)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&password=\(pwd)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&grant_type=password".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.mip.local/oauth/token")!,
        cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            ViewController.gVariables.gUser = "Error - \(error) "
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            ViewController.gVariables.gUser = response.description
        }
    })
}
```

When the app runs it reaches the let dataTask.. line and passes straight over it, so there is no response. I'm told I have the correct url, I'm running the app through an emulator while logged on so there must be something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you explain what is your problem then?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reply, I would expect the app to run the code after let dataTask.. but it doesn't so there is no response for me to deal with

Comment: that means your dataTask is nil, try to create session like this: let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

Comment: I tried that and it still did not run and dataTask was nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think here you need a **Asynchonous POST** Request code below*

```
    let urlPath: String = "http://api.mip.local/oauth/token"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var postData = NSMutableData(data: "username=\(usrName)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&password=\(pwd)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&grant_type=password".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=postData
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")
    })
```